# what is the meaning of '*' in the hello world program of Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I recently found some interest in fortran and tried to learn it but just as I found the first program i.e. the hello world code

```
print *,"hello"
end
```

I got confused. What does the `*` in the print command mean?
also.. where can I find some really good books about fortran (better if you suggest some free ones)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnc5/index.html

Comment: To be clear, the asterisk in `print *,"hello"` and `read *,i` is the same asterisk as the second asterisk discussed in the link (in `write(*,*)`).